# Axios REST Preflight OPTIONS 400 status on IE/Edge

Tags: rest, http, internet-explorer, react-redux, axios

I have a problem with my requests using Edge/IE. I'm getting a code 400 code on 
preflight OPTIONS.

I'm adding a 2 additional headers to all my requests in application with axios:

**Authorization**:

```
if ( token ) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common[ 'Authorization' ] = 'Bearer ' + token;
} else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common[ 'Authorization' ];
}
```

**Accept-Language:**

```
if ( lang ) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common[ 'Accept-Language' ] = lang;
} else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common[ 'Accept-Language' ];
}
```

Here's how my request headers works in Chrome:

```
Accept-Language: pl-PL
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJOZXcgUGFzdG9yYWwgQXBwIiwiYXVkIjoiTmV3IHBhc3RvcmFsIHVzZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTM1OTEzODUsImV4cCI6MTUxMzU5ODU4NSwidWlkIjoxMSwidHlwZSI6NCwibGFuZ3VhZ2UiOjEsImRpc3BsYXlOYW1lIjoiVGVzdG8gUHJvYm9zemN6eiJ9.qyFHZuCHC9-NpNqjY7keY7j4LE5zu5JKxK9VyAFwH60
```

Request headers in Edge:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: 52.169.186.226
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299
```

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 18 Dec 2017 11:29:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu)
```

When I remove **Accept-Language** header the application start working in Edge, but problem still exists in IE.

The only messages from browser is code http error 400 and the console log of error is:

```
description: "Network Error"
message: "Network Error"
stack: "Error: Network Error at createError (http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:68811:3) at handleError (http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:68656:7)"
```

Rest of the headers is standard for **axios**. On the backend we're using **Slimp PHP** framework.

Any idea how to debug the problem, or similar problems using standard REST requestes with React + Axios? Or what should I check in first order?

Comment: hi. Where you able to fix this issue?